# MongoDB: Collisions with $out operating on same collection

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, aggregation-framework

I am implementing query result caching in my database by issuing  `collection.aggregate(..)` with a query and an `$out` operator as the last stage.  Every so often, there will be two identical queries that attempt to output their cached result at the same time, and they collide with an error message like:

```
{"message":"$out failed: indexes of target collection dbName.collectionName changed during processing." ... }
```

The first `collection.aggregate(..)` is still writing documents into the collection when the second tries to replace the collection to start writing its own documents.

I'm looking for suggestions of how to avoid this problem.  I don't know if I can execute `$out` with some option to have it not replace the collection or if I can have it lock at the collection level rather than yielding in the middle of writing documents, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out a way to avoid the `$out` collisions directly.  However, my team member came up with this solution:

1. Randomize the name of the output collection and then once it's written,
2. Rename the collection to the desired name.

Here's the code for what I did (using the `monk` node.js driver for MongoDB):

```
function cacheResults( queryName, collection, query ) {
  var tempCollectionName = queryName + Math.random();
  var outQuery = query.concat( { $out: tempCollectionName } );
  return collection.aggregate( outQuery )
    .then( () => db.collection( tempCollectionName ) )
    .then( cachedCollection => cachedCollection.executeWhenOpened() )
    .then( nativeCollection => nativeCollection.rename( queryName, { dropTarget: true } ) )
    .then( () => db.collection( queryName ) );
```